# Fixed Jquery Mobile header and footer not working in iPhone

Tags: jquery, iphone, ios

When using Jquery mobile, the fixed header and footer is not working (ie not fixed it keeps moving) in iphone when using as a webview App. It wworks perfectly in ipad.

Spent lot of hours working this out but no luck yet.

Any help on this would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you inspect your console for JS errors and post some code so it's clearer what problem you are facing? Meanwhile, this is a pretty good resource. Helped me a lot. [Jquery Mobile Cheatsheet](http://brooky.cc/2011/04/23/jquery-mobile-cheat-sheet/).

Answer (score 0):

The bad news: jQuery Mobile is a bit glitchy when it comes to fixed header and footers - This might be what's causing your problems.

The good news: The code for fixed headers and footer has been completely rewritten for the next release - 1.1.0 which is due at the end of the month (feb 12)

Hopefully the new release will fix your problems.

Source: http://jquerymobile.com/blog/2012/01/10/upcoming-releases-1-0-1-1-1-and-beyond/

Demo of the new toolbars: http://jquerymobile.com/branches/css-fixed/docs/toolbars/bars-fixed.html